# use a metaclass as __metaclass__ of its own subclass

Tags: python

So, I have a metaclass that caches instances of objects it's classes create, to avoid duplicating instances:

```
class _CachingMeta(type):
    __cache__ = {}

    def __init__(self, n, b, d):
        # ... Do stuff...
        return super(_CachingMeta, self).__init__(n, b, d)

    def __call__(cls, *a, **kw):
        # Simplified caching key
        key = frozenset((cls, frozenset(a), frozenset(kw.items())))
        if key not in _CachingMeta.__cache__:
            _CachingMeta.__cache__[key] = super(_CachingMeta, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)
        return _CachingMeta.__cache__[key]

class StaticClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = _CachingMeta

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        pass

inst1 = StaticClass('arg1')
inst2 = StaticClass('arg1')
inst3 = StaticClass('arg3')

print (inst1)
print (inst2)
print (inst3)
```

prints:

```
<__main__.StaticClass object at 0x7f7ad8690c90>
<__main__.StaticClass object at 0x7f7ad8690c90>
<__main__.StaticClass object at 0x7f7ad8690d10>
```

I would like to also dynamically create classes and I would like the classes and the instances of those classes to be cached, and I thought I could create a metaclass that both extends `_CachingMeta` and uses it as a `__metaclass__`, but this seems to fail, and I can't wrap my head around why, e.g.:

```
class _ClassCachingMeta(_CachingMeta):
    '''
    Purpose: to cache generated classes and their instances
    '''
    __metaclass__ = _CachingMeta

def create_class(param):
    class DynamicClass(object):
        __metaclass__ = _ClassCachingMeta # A meta class that caches both  the classes it creates and their instances
        __param__ = param
    return DynamicClass
```

prints:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../test2.py", line 29, in <module>
    class _ClassCachingMeta(_CachingMeta):
  File "../test2.py", line 7, in __init__
    return super(_CachingMeta, self).__init__(n, b, d)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    descriptor '__init__' requires a 'type' object but received a 'str'
```

It seems like `_ClassCachingMeta` doesn't get a bound `__init__` method before the it's `__metaclass__.__init__` is called (which I guess are the same method/function?) (e.g.):

```
class _CachingMeta(type):
    __cache__ = {}

    def __init__(self, n, b, d):
        print ("initilizing {0}".format(self))
        print (super(_CachingMeta, self).__init__)
        return super(_CachingMeta, self).__init__(n, b, d)

    def __call__(cls, *a, **kw):
        # Simplified caching key
        key = frozenset((cls, frozenset(a), frozenset(kw.items())))
        if key not in _CachingMeta.__cache__:
            _CachingMeta.__cache__[key] = super(_CachingMeta, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)
        return _CachingMeta.__cache__[key]

class StaticClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = _CachingMeta

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        pass

class _ClassCachingMeta(_CachingMeta):
    '''
    Purpose: to cache generated classes and their instances
    '''
    __metaclass__ = _CachingMeta

def create_class(param):
    class DynamicClass(object):
        __metaclass__ = _ClassCachingMeta # Cache the class and it's instances
        __param__ = param
    return DynamicClass
```

gives:

```
initilizing <class '__main__.StaticClass'>
<method-wrapper '__init__' of _CachingMeta object at 0xc44cf0>
initilizing <class '__main__._ClassCachingMeta'>
<slot wrapper '__init__' of 'type' objects>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../test2.py", line 32, in <module>
    class _ClassCachingMeta(_CachingMeta):
  File "../test2.py", line 9, in __init__
    return super(_CachingMeta, self).__init__(n, b, d)
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    descriptor '__init__' requires a 'type' object but received a 'str'
```

Is there a straightforward way to implement this, or do I need to go with a different approach? Also, if anyone can help me understand why a class can't extend it's own `__metaclass__` that would be awesome.

Comment: duplicate  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to use a metaclass as the metaclass of its own subclasses, then subclasses are both instances and subclasses of the first class.

`super(thing, other)` can mean one of two things, depending on whether `other` is an instance of `thing` or a subclass. When `other` is *both* an instance and a subclass, `super` gets very confused.

There isn't really a good way to resolve the ambiguity for `super`. It's best to avoid this kind of situation.

Comment: Ah, OK. I think I see... Forgot that super did both. Thanks!